# A question has been answered but the user missed to accept and is now gone. How to avoid "bumping to homepage" automatically?

Tags: support

The question [MPNS](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/24329/106) has just been bumped on the homepage by the automatic bot. However the author has left the scene and there is an answer, however unaccepted. Can something be done such that B.SE "closes the case" and that "bumping-to-homepage" does not enter an infinite repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking. I think the bot will bump it if:

- No answer or
- No accepted or upvoted answer

I upvoted (so, that topic shouldn't be bumped again).

I didn't upvote originally because I could't tell whether that answer was "right" ... but based on the OP's comments they did find useful, so upvoted now.

P.S. If you don't upvote or accept this meta-answer, then the bot will also bump this meta-answer eventually.

Comment: Correction: Community bot doesn't bump questions without answers. It only bumps... "*Questions with at least 30 days of no activity, at least one answer scoring zero, and no answers scoring above that. Questions that are locked or closed will not be bumped.*" (ref. [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/241919))